# Adapt code to use in Google Slides & Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides

I am trying to amend the below code to use in both Google Slides and Google Sheets.

The current code works fine for Google Docs but I need help using the right functions for Google Slides and Google Sheets.

The current code allows me to have a font that isn't listed on docs.

My intent now is to amend the code to be usable on sheets and slides.

```
function onOpen(e){

var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();

ui.createMenu('XYV Font')

  .addItem('Load XYV Font', 'cm_Font')

  .addToUi();

}

function cm_Font() {

const choice = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();

const item = choice.getRangeElements()[0];

item

  .getElement()

  .asText()

  .setFontFamily(

   item.getStartOffset(),

   item.getEndOffsetInclusive(),

   "Noto Serif"

   );

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please briefly describe what the code do and show what you have tried to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Hi Ruben, I have done that 